# Printing zxing generated QR code with PrintHelper in Android

Tags: android, zxing

I need to print a QR code from my Android device, which works with the PrinterHelper. When I print the Bitmap it's printed way to big.
The QR code that needs to be printed is in an ImageView in my activity.

How do I print the generated QR code on paper with a width and height of, for example, 4 cm instead of 15 cm which is automatically done by Android.

I tried setting the scale mode to `SCALE_MODE_FIT`
and I tried creating a scaled bitmap

This did not work.

```
Bitmap temp = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Bitmap toPrint = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, 200, 200, false);
PrintHelper printer = new PrintHelper(MainActivity.this);
printer.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
printer.printBitmap("print test", toPrint);
```

Comment: Francois - can you share the function you used to print the generated QR. I did this but the printed QR image is too small in 4 cm paper.!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how I achieved it, the code is in **Kotlin**.

**1. Generate Barcode Bitmap(Using Zxing Library)**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeEncoder

object BarcodeUtil {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    fun generateBarcodeBitmap(barcodeData: String): Bitmap? {

        lateinit var multiFormatWriter: MultiFormatWriter

        return try {
            multiFormatWriter = MultiFormatWriter()
            val bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(barcodeData, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 4000, 800)
            val barcodeEncoder = BarcodeEncoder()
            val imgBitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix)
            imgBitmap
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.stackTrace
            e.cause
            e.message
            null
        }
    }
}
```

I generate the Barcode `Bitmap` and finally return it from the `try` block in the end.

**2.Load the Bitmap on the `ImageView`**

```
val barCode = mView.findViewById(R.id.img_barcode) as ImageView

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Glide.with(activity)
                    .load(BarcodeUtil.generateBarcodeBitmap(edtBarcode.text.toString()))
                    .into(barCode)
        }
```

I used the `Glide` library to set the `Barcode Bitmap` on my `ImageView`.
`Glide` is an Image loading library. Know more about it from [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

*One thing to remember, that downloading an entirely new library just to achieve one functionality is not recommended.*

Comment: This is not what I wish to accomplish, because I am able to display the generated barcode with the Zxing library. Let me rephrase my problem:
I want to print the generated barcode on paper with the `PrintHelper` class provided by Android. The problem is that when the `Bitmap` is printed it is printed way too big, for example with a width and height of 15 cm. My goals is to print the barcode with a height and width of, for example, 4 cm.